# Square a number function challenge doesn't work

Tags: python

The challenge is to square an input number.

```
import sys
# import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd
# from sklearn import ...

def square(x):
    return print(x ** 2)

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line, end="")
```

I don't know how to use sys.stdin I guess because I don't know how to pass through the challenge test inputs for x.

Apologies, but I can't find any answers.

Comment: You didn’t call your function.  Try `square(int(line.strip()))`.

Comment: You should also decide whether your function prints the answer to stdout or returns it to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, I guess print to stdout...? Like the test inputs are 5 and 25, but I don't know how to make it so the coding interface passes through those numbers in the function.

Comment: Like I said, *call your function*.  That's how you pass numbers *into* it.  Once you've done that you can work on debugging what you get *out* of it.  (You call a function by typing its name, `square`, and then putting the args in parens, so `square(line)` if you want to call `square` with the value of `line` as its `x` arg.)

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and I appreciate your help. At the end of the day, HackerRank wanted an x = input('') so it could pass its predetermined values through the function. To test if it worked or not.

Comment: In that case you want to do `square(x)` to actually call the function with whatever value was assigned to `x`.  (Hint -- you probably need to convert `x` from a string to an int before you can square it!)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read lines from standard input, you can use `input`. It will raise `EOFError` at end of file. To read lines successively and handle them you can just read in a loop with an exception handler for `EOFError`.

```
try:
  while True:
    line = input()
    x = int(line)
    print(square(x))
except EOFError:
  pass
```

Or for fun, wrap this up in a function that yields out the lines.

```
def read_stdin():
  try:
    while True:
      yield input()
  except EOFError:
    pass

for line in read_stdin():
  print(square(int(line)))
```